# TCP Retransmissions in Socket Configuration

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, tcp, registry

I'm using as socket in C++ (Winsock2 for windows and socket.h for linux)
is there a way to configure the TCP retransmissions to be less or more than the default?
I mean: I know there is the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
TCPMaxDataRetransmissions
```

that there I can configure it for all applications, but I want to configure only the socket in my application to be other than the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this out, but I know there is a TCP_MAXRT option that you can set.  Just did a quick search in the include directory, and I see it defined in ws2ipdef.h in Windows.

```
int maxrt = 10;
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MAXRT, &maxrt, sizeof(maxrt));
```

Comment: do you know where can I find microsoft documentation for this option?

Answer (score -1):

Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee470551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

you have good explanations how it works on different versions of windows, in the remarks section.

Comment: how this answers my question? keep alive it is not retransmissions!

Comment: TCPMaxDataRetransmissions is the number of retry for keep alive : 
On Windows Vista and later, the number of keep-alive probes (data retransmissions) is set to 10 and cannot be changed.

On Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000, the default setting for number of keep-alive probes is 5. The number of keep-alive probes is controllable through the TcpMaxDataRetransmissions and PPTPTcpMaxDataRetransmissions registry settings.