How to Preventing Retransmission and Disconnecting on RST Packet when Dialing in GO?
This is a piece of code written in Go:

func main() {
    ip := "10.12.168.168"
    port := 25565
    address := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", ip, port)
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    conn.Write([]byte("hello\n"))
    conn.Close()
}


I notice that if the remote port isn't open, net.Dial would try 5 times, sending 5 SYN packets.
I want to modify the behavior of the net.Dial function, specifically, I want to prevent the retransmission of request packets and to immediately disconnect the connection upon receiving a RST packet. What should I do to achieve this?
Retransmission after receiving RST packets
I used to use C and it's quite easy in socket programming. Maybe in GO there shouldn't be such low level concerns? I just can't help to think it's a waste to send 4 more packets after receiving a RST packet.
I know there's a net.DialTimeout("tcp", address, 1000*time.Millisecond), but not quite satisfied with it.

This is probably from the OS TCP stack. What operating system are you using?

Windows. Yeah, this is the TCP stack stuffs, sorry for I messed it up. The connect function in C on windows also send 5 SYN packets.

yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57327653/tcp-retransmission-on-rst-different-socket-behaviour-on-windows-and-linux

you can achieve similar behavior by using the net.Dialer type and setting specific options
in your main func
// Create a custom Dialer with timeout and specific control functions
dialer := &net.Dialer{
 Timeout:   1 * time.Second, // Timeout for connection attempt
 Control:   controlFunction, // Control function to handle network events
}

 

// Control function to handle network events
func controlFunction(network, address string, c syscall.RawConn) error {
 return c.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
  // handle your logic here
 })
}
